# A newly defined alias within another alias, the first excution will fail

Tags: bash, shell, alias, csh

If we define and use an alias B within another alias A, the first time execution of A will fail. For example,

```
alias A='alias B="which ls"; B;'
```

The first time excution would look like (in bash)

```
bash: B: command not found
```

The example above is a simplified construction. in practice, we might meet such usage implicitly.

The reason might be: when we execute the alias A, all expansions are carried out before execution, but B is undefined when we execute A for the first time.

So is there a way to make the first time execution successful?

The situation I met is more complex than above. My alias looks like (in tcsh)

> > alias A 'cmd1; cmd2; B -v arg_of_B; cmd3; cmd4;'

where, B is an alias defined by cmd2. In addition, the definition of B looks like (in tcsh)

> > alias B 'source /path/to/script.csh'

So using eval to postpone the execution of B might not work, because eval will fork a new shell to execute the command. Another factor making this more complex is there are arguments following the alias. I tried to use exec but without achieving success.

Comment: You might consider if a shell function is more appropriate than an alias in your situation.

Comment: Yes, a shell function if available will be useful, however, we cannot define functions in tcsh.

Comment: Is there any `bash` component to this question, then?

Comment: I bielive this applies to bash too. Defining a shell function is one solution for bash, while using eval is another elegant solution for both bash and tcsh, as pointed out by choroba below.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be simplified to a simple alias. The following fails for the first time as well:

```
alias A=ls ; A
```

To postpone the expansion, you can use `eval`:

```
alias A=df ; eval A
```

(Tested in bash and tcsh).

Comment: I have updated the post about the more complex situation I meet. Could you please help check that?

Comment: @YangLi: `eval` does not run in a subshell.

Comment: YES, you are right, eval is the ultimate solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For those who are confused with exec, eval, and source in shell like me, I find a useful link: [link](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/54347-bash-shell-exec-eval-source-looking-help-understand.html)